# PHP multiple image upload with checking size and type

Tags: php

I design a form to upload multiple image using PHP and i want to check the type and size of image.
But my code won't work successfully.
How can I correct the code?

**HTML input file(part of file upload):**

```
<input type="file" class="test" name="file_array[]">
<input type="file" class="test" name="file_array[]">
```

**PHP code**

```
<?php
if (isset($_FILES['file_array'])) {
    $name_array     = $_FILES['file_array']['name'];
    $tmp_name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['tmp_name'];
    $type_array     = $_FILES['file_array']['type'];
    $size_array     = $_FILES['file_array']['size'];

    $allowedTypes = array(IMAGETYPE_PNG, IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_GIF);
    $detectedType = exif_imagetype($tmp_name_array);

    $checktype = in_array($detectedType, $allowedTypes);
}

if ($checktype == false) {
    echo "type error";
    echo "</br>";
} elseif ($size_array > 2097152) {
    echo "type error";
    echo "</br>";
} else {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++) {
        if (move_uploaded_file(
            $tmp_name_array[$i], "upload/" . $name_array[$i]
        )
        ) {
            echo $name_array[$i] . " upload is complete<br>";
        } else {
            echo "function failed for " . $name_array[$i] . "<br>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You should set the name `file_array[]` to `file_array` - as the name is not actually an array, its the reference to the object which is posted to your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing an array to `exif_imagetype()`, it should be a string with filename, for your example, you should iterate through your array or use something like:

```
// Get type from first image
$detectedTypeImage1 = exif_imagetype($tmp_name_array[0]);
$detectedTypeImage2 = exif_imagetype($tmp_name_array[1]);
```

Then you are wrongly compare an `array` with an `int`

```
$size_array > 2097152
```

you could do like the first example I gave or you could use a loop through the array, like:

```
foreach($size_array as $imageSize){
    if($imageSize > 2097152){
        echo "type error SIZE";
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

#### Full example

```
/**
    * Reorder the uploaded files array to simply the use of foreach
    * 
    * @param array $file_post
    * @return array
    */
    function reArrayFiles(&$file_post) {

    $file_ary = array();
    $file_count = count($file_post['name']);
    $file_keys = array_keys($file_post);

    for ($i=0; $i<$file_count; $i++) {
        foreach ($file_keys as $key) {
            $file_ary[$i][$key] = $file_post[$key][$i];
        }
    }

    return $file_ary;
}



// Array reArranged
$file_ary = reArrayFiles($_FILES['file_array']);

$allowedTypes = array(IMAGETYPE_PNG, IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_GIF);


// For each file...
foreach($file_ary as $key => $file){

    static $i = 1;

    if($file['error'] == 4){
        echo 'No file uploaded on field '.$i++.'.<br>';
        continue;
    }

    $errors = false;

    // Check type, if not allowed tell's you wich one have the problem
    if(!in_array(exif_imagetype($file['tmp_name']), $allowedTypes)){
        echo '<span style="color:red">Filename '.$file['name'].' <b>type</b> is not allowed.</span><br>';
        $errors = true;
    }

    // Check size, if exceed allowed size tell's you wich one have the problem
    if($file['size'] > 2097152){
        echo '<span style="color:red">Filename '.$file['name'].' exceeds maximum allowed <b>size</b></span>.<br>';
        $errors = true;
    }


    // If we don't have errors let's upload files to the server
    if(!$errors){
        if (move_uploaded_file(
                $file['tmp_name'], "../upload/" . $file['name'])
        ){
            echo $file['name'] . " upload is complete<br>";

        }else{
            echo "Uploaded failed for " . $file['name'] . "<br>";
        }   
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Don't forget to use `is_uploaded_file()` too.

Comment: I try your code. But still can not check the image type.

Comment: I have edit my answer, you just need to follow the logic.
Check my answer again.

Comment: There are some problem for the example ,if i just upload one image, your example cannot work.

Also, if i upload two file,file1 has valid file type n file2 has invalid type, the code cannot do the validation, both file can not upload to server.
How can i fix these two problem

Comment: I was trying to explain you for you be able to reach your objective, you should understand what is made :)
See my edit answer.

Comment: The problem for your new answer is if i just upload one file in my form , the code still will do validation for two input because my form have 2 space for me upload file.  if i just upload one file , i will see (Warning: exif_imagetype(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\wamp\www\Paul\uplaoditem\uploadc.php on line 37).

Comment: Check if you have copy all my new answer!
If no image is upload the script will not make any validations.


Make shure you have my last edit anwser!